# Line or Low or High Voltage Twisted Cable?

Tags: power-supply, cables

I understand that telecommunication cables are often twisted to cancel out electromagnetic interference (EMI) from external sources, e.g., crosstalk.

Are power cables ever twisted and if so, why?

Comment: As a general rule -- round cords, armored cables, and wire-on-messenger (triplex/quadruplex service drops) are twisted -- flat cords obviously aren't, and NM (Romex&trade;) isn't either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Power cables are twisted for a variety of reasons; one important example is the
power wiring that delivers AC from a pole-top transformer to your home.  There 
is one high-tensile (steel or aluminum) cable that anchors
the conductors, and twisting the conductors around that cable keeps them from
drooping and stretching under tension.

Flexible power cables are usually twisted insulated conductors inside a
round sheath, which acts to equalize any tension that might act on the
cable: the wire path is not a straight line, so pulling on the cable
doesn't stretch any of the wires, just stretches the sheath (and the
cables inside become more or less straightened until the tension is relieved).

When a power cable is twisted, look for a mechanical reason, not electromagnetic
interference.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, power cables are twisted for exactly the same reason.  If you have sensor cables running down the same duct as power cables, twisting will minimize magnetic field coupling.

Read up on ethernet CAT6 specs.  They will tell you pretty much everything you need to know about it.  Each pair is twisted with e different prime number of twists per unit length, with the intent to not have pairs of wires line up with their number of twists.  Twisting the pair causes lines of flux to cancel themselves out.

Comment: Thanks for answering Brian.  Why is Romex type power cable, for example, not twisted then?

Comment: I imagine users of Romex are not interested in noise getting into the Romex, and if they are interested in noise coupling into other circuits from the Romex, then they need to use something else besides Romex.  I.e., it's beyond the specification for Romex wire.     Aircraft cables used for power are very often twisted, and usually shielded as well.